# How to rigorously prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\prod\limits_{r=1}^n \frac{n^2-r}{n^2+r} = e^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I saw this problem:

> Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\prod\limits_{r=1}^n \frac{n^2-r}{n^2+r} $

I tried to prove this problem and got:

$$\ln(1+x) = \sum_{k=1}^ \infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^k}{ k} \ \ \ \ \text{ with radius of convergence = 1 }$$
$$\ln(1-x)=- \sum_{k=1}^ \infty \frac{ x^k}{ k}  \ \ \ \ \text{ with radius of convergence = 1 }$$

$$L:= \lim_{n \to \infty }\prod_{r=1}^n \frac{n^2-r}{n^2+r}$$
$$\ln(L) =\lim_{n \to \infty } \sum_{r=1}^n \ln\left(1 - \frac{r}{n^2}\right) - \ln\left(1 + \frac{r}{n^2}\right) $$
$$=-2\lim_{n \to \infty } \sum_{r=1}^n  \sum_{k\in 2\mathbb{ N}-1} \frac{ \left(\frac{r}{n^2} \right)^k}{ k}  = -1$$

$$L=e^{-1}$$

---

But this proof missing a few details and  tried to complete it

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{\sum_{r=1}^n r^k}{n^{k+1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{\sum\limits_{r=1}^n\left(\frac rn\right)^k}n=\int_0^1x^kdx=\frac1{k+1}$$
hence for all $k >1 $ $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{\sum_{r=1}^n r^k}{n^{2k}} =\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n^{k+1}}{(k+1)n^{2k}}=\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{ n ^{1-k} }{k+1}=0.$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \sum_{r=1}^n  \sum_{k\in 2\mathbb{N}-1} \frac{ \left(\frac{r}{n^2} \right)^k}{ k}=\lim_{n \to \infty }   \sum_{k\in 2\mathbb{N}-1} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{ \left(\frac{r}{n^2} \right)^k}{ k}=\lim_{n \to \infty }   \sum_{k\in 2\mathbb{N}-1}  \frac{ \sum\limits_{r=1}^nr^k}{kn^{2k}}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}+\lim_{n \to \infty }   \sum_{k\in 2\mathbb{N}+1}\frac{ \sum\limits_{r=1}^nr^k}{kn^{2k}},$$
and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty }   \sum_{k\in 2\mathbb{N}+1}\frac{ \sum\limits_{r=1}^nr^k}{kn^{2k}}\le\lim_{n \to \infty }   \sum_{k=3}^\infty\frac{ \sum\limits_{r=1}^nr^k}{n^{2k}}=\sum_{k=3}^\infty\lim_{n \to \infty }   \frac{ \sum\limits_{r=1}^nr^k}{n^{2k}}=\sum_{k=3}^\infty0=0.$$

The problem is I am not sure what is the justification of changing the order of limit and sum in the last step. Is my proof complete? and if not, how to complete it?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151843/discussion-on-question-by-pie-how-to-rigorously-prove-that-lim-limits-n-to); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last step $\lim_{n \to \infty }   \sum_{k=3}^\infty\dots=\sum_{k=3}^\infty\lim_{n \to \infty }\dots$ is indeed lacking some justification.

You can repair (and simplify) your proof the following way: instead of your tricky evaluation of $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{\sum_{r=1}^n r^k}{n^{k+1}}$, just notice a rough upper bound:
$\sum_{r=1}^nr^k\le\sum_{r=1}^nn^k=n^{k+1}$, hence
$$\sum_{k\in 2\mathbb{N}+1}\frac{\sum_{r=1}^nr^k}{kn^{2k}}\le\sum_{k\ge2}\frac{n^{1-k}}k<\sum_{k\ge2}n^{1-k}=\frac1{n-1}\to0.$$

Answer (score 6):

By noting that $ \log(1-x) - \log(1+x) = -2 \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1-t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t $, you can prove that

$$ -2x \geq \log(1-x) - \log(1+x) \geq -\frac{2x}{1-x^2}. $$

Then for $n \geq 1$ and $0 \leq r \leq n$,

$$ -\frac{2r}{n^2} \geq \log(1-r/n^2) - \log(1+r/n^2) \geq -\frac{2r}{n^2-(r/n)^2} \geq - \frac{2r}{n^2-1}, $$

hence by summing this for $ r = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ we get:

$$ - \frac{n(n-1)}{n^2} \geq \log \prod_{r=1}^{n} \frac{n^2 - r}{n^2 + r} \geq - \frac{n(n-1)}{n^2 - 1}. $$

This is enough to conclude that $\log L = -1$ and hence $L = e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

You can first prove that $\mathrm{log}\tfrac{n^2-r}{n^2+r}$ is bounded away from $-2r/n^2$ by $\mathcal{O}(r^3.n^{-6})$.

Then you sum over all $r$ values and obtain on the one hand $-1-1/n$ and an error term $\mathcal{O}(n^4.n^{-6})=\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$.

This result is a bit stronger than needed by the way since it gives you the rate of convergence towards the limit.